# Why doesn't the $3d$ gravitino have a quantized "level"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, chern-simons-theory

The action for the $3d$ gravitino is

$$S_g=-\int d^3x\bar{\Psi}_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu\lambda\nu}\partial_{\lambda}\Psi_{\nu}$$

Where $\gamma^{\mu\lambda\nu}=-\epsilon^{\mu\lambda\nu}$. This has a striking resemblance with the abelian Chern-Simons action

$$S_{CS}=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int d^3xA_{\mu}\epsilon^{\mu\lambda\nu}\partial_{\lambda}A_{\nu}$$

It is well known that $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I have read [Topological mass quantization and parity violation in 2 + 1 dimensional QED](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321387902549) and [Topological quantization and cohomology](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01212452), and I was wondering how specifically these arguments fail for the gravitino?

The quantization condition for the gauge field $A$ can be traced to making a Wilson line well defined, and I am not able to construct anything analogous to the Wilson line for a gravitino, since the naive construction $\int_C\Psi_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ has an open spinor index. I suspect something about the gravitino being a Grassmann valued field also has something to do with this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good and interesting question!

These systems at first sight are similar. They describe off-shell different degrees of freedom. But on-shell due to gauge invariance we do not have local degrees of freedom.

But quantization conditions for Abelian Chern-Simons theory are quite tricky. One of the reason for quantisation is possibility topological nontrivial field configuration, like fluxes $\int dx^\mu dx^\nu F_{\mu\nu}$. (See for example [David Tong: Lectures on Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html), section 8.4.1.)

In contrast, in spin 3/2 theory, field strength has a spinor index
$$
G_{\mu\nu|\alpha} = \partial_\mu \Psi_{\nu \alpha} - \partial_\nu \Psi_{\mu \alpha}
$$

And so we do not have rotationally invariant definition of flux. This doesn't lead to quantization of coefficient.